# How do I create custom error popup message in Java without JOptionPane?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, error-handling, popup, joptionpane

I'm currently trying to pop up an error message popup that says "Sorry! That caused an error!" Throwing an exception doesn't let me customize the popup message, and I read about JOptionPane, which I cannot use, as Google App Engine has blacklisted all javax.swing.* libraries.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please post this as an answer so it can be noticed by the community

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is a web platform, you need to use web technologies `(html/css/javascript)`, not native code libraries like swing.